# password with special characters in batch scripts

Tags: batch-file, special-characters

I think I have a problem with the special caracter `%`.

How can I get my program to work with a string like: `toto%titi`?

Regards,

Answer (score 3):

The solution to this issue is to double the special character in the string

`toto%titi` becomes `toto%%titi`

Regards.